# Is there a (good) 3-way merge driver for ASCII-DOC files?

Tags: merge, git-merge, asciidoc

Is there a (good) 3-way  merge driver for ASCII-DOC files?

I tried Google, but did not find something.

Normal text-based 3-way merge does not work, because it does not understand the file structure and mixes up changes of different sections.

Comment: I'm not aware of a diff tool that understands AsciiDoc. You can get p4merge when you download P4V (the Helix Visual Client): https://www.perforce.com/downloads/helix-visual-client-p4v